# I can't use APC. What Php framework can I use?

Tags: php, apc

I have to build a couple of websites that will be hosted in a shared hosting environment. Both applications have different functionalities that can't be easily solved by the usual cms. It's not commercial stuff, so there's no money to afford anything else, and besides, the space is kindly offered for free. The environment is php 5.3.6.

I normally would pick symfony 2 to develop quickly and save a lot of headaches, but there's a big problem with performances: without APC or equivalent accelerator, things are really slow.

I know there are lots of "what's the best php framework?" questions out there, but this is aimed to a specific environment, to avoid a specific problem.

What is the best solution to develop in php when you don't have accelerators?

What frameworks or components do you suggest?

Comment: Well, Codeigniter is very lightweight and fast

Comment: I was going to suggest CodeIgniter too

Comment: Congratulations - you both decided to suggest one of two worst frameworks in PHP.

Comment: codeigniter very fast and elegent

Comment: And of course, there's always the option of not using a framework at all. (just to throw a curve ball into the mix....  :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Microframeworks:

Silex http://silex.sensiolabs.org/ - based on Symfony 2 so it might be familiar to you

Slim http://www.slimframework.com/

PIP http://gilbitron.github.com/PIP/

Flight: http://flightphp.com/

Yaf: http://www.yafdev.com/

Plus some (*pinch of salt*) benchmarks: http://www.ruilog.com/blog/view/b6f0e42cf705.html

Comment: Flight seems interesting.. Slim is nice, I already used it for a little json api, but I was looking for something more quick to develop with.
So I'm probably going for silex, although I'm not happy since it has no stable release yet (I guess we have to wait symfony 2.2).
Still, I don't know where are the performance bottlenecks and so what bundles/libraries I can use and what others not... I suppose doctrine is probably the big time-drainer, and maybe twig is heavy too?